# Unexpected type mismatch when using Scala generics

Tags: scala, generics

I have a simple scenario that is yielding a type mismatch when using Scala generics, and it's not clear why or how to resolve it.

```
trait Foo
case class Bar() extends Foo

trait FooGetter[T <: Foo] {
  def get: T = Bar() // Error
}
```

The error:

> type mismatch; found   :
>   Bar  required: T

Any hints?

Comment: Well you declared `T` as a sub-type of `Foo`, while `Bar` is a sub-type of `Foo`. That doesn't guarantee that it will be any sub-type of `Foo`. For example if you made another class `Bazz` which also extends from `Foo` and try to create an instance of `FooGetter` parametrized in `Bazz` then an instance of `Bar` on the get would be a type missmatch.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I'd like to be able to return `Bar()` from within my method. In that case, how should I declare this to compile?

Comment: Well you can just change the type signature to return a `Bar`, but then the type parameter and the trait itself becomes unnecessary. I think what you really want is to be able to get the correct instance of Foot implicitly by calling something like `FooGeter[Bar].get`.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez That makes sense, but FooGetter should treat all T things as `Foo`. I can cast `Bar().asInstanceOf[T]` which works fine, but I'm not sure why it's needed.

Comment: I think you should edit the question to provide a better explanation of the main problem, and provide as many details as you can.

Comment: If you want all things returned to be treated just as `Foo` why don't specify the return type as the `Foo`? You still can return `Bar()` in the implementation but for the users of the `FooGetter` interface it will be just any `Foo`

Answer (score 1):

Here `T <: Foo` means `Foo` is the **upper bound** of type `T`.

[image]

As you can see, there is no relationship between `Bar` and `T`, so the casting cannot happen in an implicit way.

Of course, if you can guarantee the casting safety, you can cast it using `asInstanceOf` in an explicit way.

On the other hand, the following is fine when `T` is the super while `Foo` is the child.

```
trait FooGetter[T >: Foo] {
  def get: T = Bar()
}
```

Comment: this gives my an exception in Scalafiddle - see https://scalafiddle.io/sf/ZbDrxir/0

Comment: the point is that `new FooGetter[Bar]{}` is illegal, since `T >: Foo` means that `Bar` is not allowed here.

Comment: my answer is trying to figure out the reason why implicit casting is not allowed in the question; the usage of  upper bound or lower bound is not my point.

Comment: ok, but how would my example than look like - can you create a new version in ScalaFiddle?

Comment: please see https://scalafiddle.io/sf/FprLTSu/0. My answer may be a little misleading.

Comment: A simple way is to use `asInstanceOf` to cast type, as the `T >: Foo` is not the one he/she intends.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the code like this:

```
trait Foo
case class Bar() extends Foo

trait FooGetter {
  def get: Foo = Bar()
}
```

`FooGetter` is tightly linked to `Foo` anyway, there is no point in making `FooGetter` generic. (Note, `Bar` is a `Foo` for the scala type checker.)

Comment: Thanks - It's generic because it's a simplification of an actual getter that is subclassed and used for other types, so in my case it's needed.

Comment: In that case, can you please elaborate the question?

Answer (score 0):

What always works is `asInstanceOf`, in your Example:

```
trait Foo
case class Bar() extends Foo

trait FooGetter[T <: Foo] {
  def get: T = Bar().asInstanceOf[T]
}
```

So this works:

```
println(new FooGetter[Bar]{}.get) // Bar()
```

**But** as Seth Tisue points out:

> there's no point in using generics at all if the resulting code isn't
>   actually generic.

Comment: @ Downvoter - please can you explain why you should not use `asInstanceOf[T]` - or why you downvoted - I am here to learn and Josh Stone still has no correct answer.

Comment: You can `asInstanceOf` your way out of any type mismatch. I don't think that counts as a solution, because the resulting code is just plain wrong, it happens to work in the `Bar` case, but it's wrong in general, there's no point in using generics at all if the resulting code isn't actually generic. As for what I would consider a proper answer, @chenzhongpu's answer seems about as good as anyone can do, without more context in the question about what the real problem OP is trying to solve is. See also Erik's answer and comment. Hope this helps.

Comment: @SethTisue thanks for your explanation - I agree with your point and adjusted my answer.